# Despeckling Ultrasound images using Diffusion Filtering

Tags: image-processing, matlab

I am working on Despeckling Ultrasound images. I have been trying out some basic filters and their hybrid combination.. Now I would like to try Diffusion Filtering techniques to despeckle the ultrasound images. I don't know anything about the diffusion filtering techniques (Isotropic diffusion or Perona Malik Anisotropic Diffusion Filter). I would like to learn from the basic. Please suggest some books to learn about Diffusion techniques.. Please keep in mind that I am not an advanced learner.

I did google and found this book ([Despeckle Filtering Algorithms and Software for Ultrasound Imaging By Christos P. Loizou, Constantinos S. Pattichis, Costas Pattichis](http://books.google.co.in/books?id=EVoNLGlAbnkC&printsec=frontcover&dq=despeckling&hl=en&sa=X&ei=SxfxUpurPMS3rgfft4H4AQ&ved=0CCwQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=despeckling&f=false)) very useful. But I couldn't able to buy it. If anyone have the PDF of this book (even 1 or 2 chapters), please provide me the link. Also provide some useful links to learn these techniques

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reference: [Anisotropic Diﬀusion in Image Processing by Joachim Weickert](http://www.lpi.tel.uva.es/muitic/pim/docus/anisotropic_diffusion.pdf)

No matter where would you learn the theoretical background of the diffusion techniques, I would like to apply the Matlab implementation on the [2nd formal definition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anisotropic_diffusion#Formal_definition) of anisotropic diffusion, it is not difficult. I used the ultrasound B-scan image you used before.

```
I=imread('ultrasound.png');
I=rgb2gray(I);
subplot(1,2,1)
imshow(I);
[rows, cols]=size(I);
diff = double(I); % original image
lambda = 0.25; 
niter = 10;
Co = 20;
for i = 1:10  % iterations

  % Construct diffl which is the same as diff but
  % has an extra padding of zeros around it.
  diffl = zeros(rows+2, cols+2);
  diffl(2:rows+1, 2:cols+1) = diff;

  % North, South, East and West differences
  deltaN = diffl(1:rows,2:cols+1)   - diff;  
  deltaS = diffl(3:rows+2,2:cols+1) - diff;  
  deltaE = diffl(2:rows+1,3:cols+2) - diff;  
  deltaW = diffl(2:rows+1,1:cols)   - diff;

  cN = 1./(1 + (deltaN/Co).^2);
  cS = 1./(1 + (deltaS/Co).^2);
  cE = 1./(1 + (deltaE/Co).^2);
  cW = 1./(1 + (deltaW/Co).^2);

  diff = diff + lambda*(cN.*deltaN + cS.*deltaS + cE.*deltaE + cW.*deltaW);

end
subplot(1,2,2),imshow(uint8(diff))
```

You can see the edge preserving effect of diffusion filter (right) compared with the speckled noisy image (left).

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for your help.. Any other despeckling algorithms which preserves edges?

Comment: Thanks Premnath. As far as I know, bilateral filter is the most often referred edge preserving method. Here is the code for your reference: http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/12191-bilateral-filtering/content/Bilateral%20Filtering/bfilter2.m  It's a little bit more complicated than diffusion though. Thanks

Comment: Hi Lennon, I am curious why you implemented the diff like this, cant you do it through convolution with a kernel? Or is this way you have necessary? Thanks.

Comment: @TheGrapeBeyond Thank you Grape. Yes you can implement such an 1D derivative by convolution with [-1 1] kernel (along x direction). It seems like the subtraction is a little bit faster than convolution, although they are both O(n). This post shows some comparison on the calculation of gradient, which is similar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18958231/fast-computation-of-a-gradient-of-an-image-in-matlab  Thanks

Comment: Any books, PDFs or links to learn theory of diffusion filtering ? please suggest some..

Comment: @PremnathD I added a link in my answer, on the top, for your reference, Thanks

Comment: @PremnathD you are very welcome

Comment: @lennon310 Hello again, I tried following your code and the wiki yesterday, but I cannot seem to follow. How is your last equation related to the wiki equation, ($\frac{\delta I}{\delta t}$)? Also the wiki shows $\nabla c$? The $c$ in the wiki is a constant, while in your code its a matrix... very confused. May you please expand how your code is related to the wiki piece? Its interesting stuff and thank you for that but it would be good to elucidate. Many thanks.

Comment: @TheGrapeBeyond I used the formula in formal definition part to calculate c, where c is the diffusion rate depending on d(diff)/d(t) at every pixel (so it's not a constant). And during image update, similar with what people usually do in gradient descent, diff= diff+lambda*c*(d(diff)/dt). Thanks